# Overriding Crispy Forms template fails

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to override default templates for tabs in Crispy Forms 1.7.0. As a first step, I tried to copy the relevant template ([templates/bootstrap3/layout/tab-link.html](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/blob/1.7.0/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap3/layout/tab-link.html)) from crispy forms templates into my app template directory (myapp/templates/crispy_overrides/tab-link.html) but it stopped rendering the tabs properly when I tried to use the template in my dirs in layouts.

Below is the relevant part from my form layout object and the template. Everything works fine if I comment out the `template=...` lines.

Am I doing it wrong?

```
TabHolder(
    Tab('D.DDD°',
        'latitude',
        'longitude',
        template='crispy_overrides/tab-link.html',
        ),
    Tab(
        'DD°, DD.DD\'',
        'lat_dmm_d',
        'lat_dmm_m',
        'lon_dmm_d',
        'lon_dmm_m',
        template='crispy_overrides/tab-link.html',
    ),
    Tab(
        'DD°, DD\', SS.SS\'\'',
        'lat_dms_d',
        'lat_dms_m',
        'lat_dms_s',
        'lon_dms_d',
        'lon_dms_m',
        'lon_dms_s',
        template='crispy_overrides/tab-link.html',
    ),
    Tab('UTM',
        'utm_zone',
        'utmx',
        'utmy',
        template='crispy_overrides/tab-link.html'
    ),
),
```

`tab-link.html`

```
<li class="tab-pane{% if 'active' in link.css_class %} active{% endif %}"><a href="#{{ link.css_id }}" data-toggle="tab">{{ link.name|capfirst }}{% if tab.errors %}!{% endif %}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course I figured it out right after posting the question. *sigh*.

Apparently, for Tab objects, you need to override `link_template` and not `template`. Looks like this might be a bug.

Relevant part from the Layout Class:

```
class Tab(Container):
    """
    Tab object. It wraps fields in a div whose default class is "tab-pane" and
    takes a name as first argument. Example::
        Tab('tab_name', 'form_field_1', 'form_field_2', 'form_field_3')
    """
    css_class = 'tab-pane'
    link_template = '%s/layout/tab-link.html' # Notice how it isn't 'template'

    def render_link(self, template_pack=TEMPLATE_PACK, **kwargs):
        """
        Render the link for the tab-pane. It must be called after render so css_class is updated
        with active if needed.
        """
        link_template = self.link_template % template_pack
        return render_to_string(link_template, {'link': self})
```